# GBM and RF ensamble in caret

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, gbm

I am currently trying to build a stacked model using the caretEnsemble package, using random forest and generalized boosted model as base models. However, I keep receiving the following error after running the caretEnsemble function:

```
Error in check_caretList_model_types(list_of_models) : 
Not yet implemented for multiclass problems
```

Having done some research on the problem, I have noticed that this function works best when the models are built with train() function (which has been done) and sometimes depends on the format of the training data. Since this is part of an assignment, I wont post the data processing code, but will provide a link to it - [LINK](https://github.com/askerovk/misc/blob/master/training.csv)

And here is the code I am trying to run on it.

```
training<-read.csv("training.csv")

control<- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, 
    savePredictions = TRUE, classProbs = TRUE)

metric<-"Accuracy"

set.seed(5937)

fit1<-caretList(classe~., data=training, trControl=control, metric=metric, 
    methodList = c("rf", "gbm"))

fit2<-caretEnsemble(fit1)
```

Could you help me figure out if this is a technical limitation of the package or am I trying to combine incompatible models? Is there a workaround to this or perhaps a better way to build the stacked model?

Many thanks,
Kamran.

**UPDATE**

No replies so far, so let me post an update. I tried to combine the two models in a manual way, by using a generalized additive mode. The models are same as from earlier code and validation set can be found here - [LINK](https://github.com/askerovk/misc/blob/master/validation.csv):

```
val<-read.csv("validation.csv")

pred1<- predict(fit1$rf, val)

pred2<-predict(fit1$gbm, val)

predDF<- data.frame(pred1, pred2, classe=val$classe)

fitcomb<-train(classe~., method="gam", data=predDF)

pred3<- predict(fitcomb, predDF)

confusionMatrix(pred3, predDF$classe)
```

This is the result I got:
    Confusion Matrix and Statistics

```
Reference
Prediction 
        A   B   C   D   E
     A 742  55  88  60  46
     B 304 657 553 543 630
     C   0   0   0   0   0
     D   0   0   0   0   0
     E   0   0   0   0   0
```

For some reason, my model is only recognizing two classes in the data, when there should be 5.

Can someone help me get either of the two approaches to work? Also, this is my first time posting questions here - do let me know if I can improve the question quality in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states:

```
Error in check_caretList_model_types(list_of_models) : 
Not yet implemented for multiclass problems
```

And this is exactly the problem. Github issue [#191](https://github.com/zachmayer/caretEnsemble/pull/191), support for multiclass models is still open. The feature has not be implemented.